# Inversão de array (posições)

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando fazer uma inversão de um array na linguagem `C`.

Por exemplo: tenho um array `[1, 2, 3]`, preciso inverter os números no MESMO array, dando uma saída assim: `[3,2,1]`. Estou tentando, mas ao chegar na segunda posição do array, o mesmo começa a se espelhar. Segue o código e obrigado desde já:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x[4];
    int i, j, aux;

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        printf("\nEscreva um numero\n");
        scanf("\n%d", & x[i]);  
    }

    i = 0;
    for (j = 3; j >= 0; j = j - 1){
        aux = x[i];
        x[i] = x[j];
        x[j] = aux;

        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        printf("\n numero: %d\n", x[i]);    
    }       
}
```

Comment: Está *espelhando* pq você não está usando a variável **aux** para guardar o valor que está deslocando....

Comment: Galera, eu refiz o "programa", mas ainda está espelhando... por exemplo, coloco (1, 2, 3, 4) a saída correta seria (4, 3, 2, 1). Mas a saída está sendo (4, 3, 3, 4).

Comment: editei com o novo código (Que ainda continua espelhando);

Comment: Tente substituir a linha `x[j] = x[i];` por `x[j] = aux;`

Comment: certo, você está usando a **aux** para receber o valor mas não está recolocando o valor de **aux** no vetor

Comment: Pessoal, desculpa a minha ignorância, eu refiz conforme pediram, mas na saída está repetindo o Array de entrada. Por exemplo: Coloco (1, 2, 3, 4)... a saída está sendo (1, 2, 3, 4). Será que o loop que fiz de saída está errado?

Answer (score 4):

### A resposta pra pergunta se resume em uma linha:

Você não pode passar da metade do vetor no seu loop, senão está invertendo e "desinvertendo" de novo ao passar do meio.

### Apenas como complemento, segue código:

Esqueça o `z` e faça direto no `x`

```
for (j = tamanho-1; j > (tamanho/2); j = j - 1){
    aux = x[i];
    x[i] = x[j];
    x[i] = aux;        
    i++;
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/fBegDg)**.

Se quiser otimizar um pouco (e deixar o tamanho mais flexível), veja mais um exemplo:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x[7];
    int i, aux;
    int tamanho = sizeof(x)/sizeof(int);

    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        printf("\nEscreva um numero\n");
        scanf("\n%d", & x[i]);  
    }

    for (i = 0; i <= (tamanho/2); i++){
        aux = x[i];
        x[i] = x[tamanho-i-1];
        x[tamanho-i-1] = aux;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        printf("numero: %d\n", x[i]);    
    }
}
```

Também funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/HfsP5d)**.

Note que a resposta do Daniel Grillo (que já recebeu meu +1) também tem tem uma solução elegante, que é verificar o loop comparando `j` com `i`, e poderia ser otimizada para `for (j = 3; j > i; j--){`

Comment: Bacco, obrigado por responder a minha pergunta... mas na saída, ainda está repetindo os valores de entrada. :(

Comment: pus um demo funcional no IDEONE

Comment: e mais um com umas melhorias

Comment: @MatheusMinguini tentei destacar melhor a parte importante, que é não passar do meio do vetor, espero que assim consiga entender porque os demos no IDEONE funcionam, e comparar com seu teste. Perceba o `j < (tamanho/2)` no for (que no seu caso pode ser resumido pra `j < 2`

Comment: Mito obrigado pelo seu tempo, Bacco! Eu entendi! Desejo muito sucesso a você

Comment: Que bom que deu certo, qq coisa deixe comentário aqui. Se puder, marque alguma das respostas como aceita para fechar a questão como resolvida. Basta clicar no V verdinho do lado da pontuação. A aceitação só pode ser em uma delas, mas lembre-se que em breve você poderá votar positivo em todas as postagens que te ajudarem, mesmo em perguntas de terceiros (e pode positivar mais de uma resposta neste caso, apenas a aceitação que é em uma só).

Answer (score 2):

Tente assim:

```
i = 0;
for (j = 3; j >= i; j--){
    aux = x[j]; 
    x[j] = x[i];
    x[i] = aux;
    i++;    
}
```